# Recommend a good DVD or BD replacement drive that can read older CD-R/DVD+R media?

Tags: dvd, hardware-rec, optical-drive, blu-ray, compact-disc

So I have a bunch of older CD-R (and a few DVD+R) discs that are either suffering from "bit rot", or a case of crappy no-name Chinese DVD drives being unable to read some or all of anymore.  I just threw my last no-name DVD drive in the trash after it ejected a disk still spinning causing it to scratch to the point of being useless, so I'm looking for a replacement drive this time around with an eye for quality over a dirt cheap price.

I'd prefer a BD drive, but I'll take any suggestions for good, reliable DVD or BD drives that people have reported having good success with for reading older burned media.  Any takers?

Comment: IF a drive can read new media, it can read old media. Now, the quality of the drive of course is a completely different matter..

Comment: Is there something that the leading hardware review web sites not give you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't help a huge amount, but: when I was putting together my current PC in 2007, the first DVD drive I tried wouldn't read a rental DVD I had at the time, so I swapped it for my current drive which read it fine. I can't remember what the first one was but it was a known brand of good repute. The current one is an LG HL-DT-ST DVDRAM GSA-H62N.

Comment: I think I have the same model drive as you, and would gladly second the recommendation toward it (or other LG drives) as LG has done exceedingly well for me and my wife in both our computers.